# URL Template Tag works in one instance, but can't find path with kwargs of '{'pk': ''}' in another

Tags: python, django

I've assigned a navbar link a URL template tag using named paths, and I'm passing the keyword argument of pk to that URL. When I click on the link directly, it passes the kwarg as it should and I get the DetailView that is intended. However, when i attempt to view other DetailView's in my app, I receive the error of: Reverse for 'my_company_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['console/(?P[0-9]+)/mycompany/$'].

.html snippet

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'user_console:my_company_detail' 
pk=request.user.primary_company_pk %}">My Company</a>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [path('login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="user_console/login.html"),name='login'),
path('change-password/',auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name="user_console/change-password.html"),name='change_password'),
path('home/',views.HomepageView.as_view(),name='home'),
path('logged-out/',auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='user_console/logged_out.html'),name='logged_out'),
path('requests/',views.RequestListView.as_view(),name='request_list'),
path('request/<int:pk>/',views.RequestDetailView.as_view(),name='request_detail'),
path('consumers/',views.ConsumerListView.as_view(),name='consumer_list'),
path('consumer/create/',views.ConsumerCreateView.as_view(),name='consumer_create'),
path('consumer/<int:pk>/',views.ConsumerDetailView.as_view(),name='consumer_detail'),
path('companies/',views.CompanyListView.as_view(),name='company_list'),
path('company/<int:pk>/',views.CompanyDetailView.as_view(),name='company_detail'),
path('company/create/',views.CompanyCreateView.as_view(),name='company_create'),
path('request/<int:pk>/edit',views.RequestUpdate.as_view(),name='request_update'),
path('request/create/',views.RequestCreateView.as_view(),name='request_create'),
path('requests/export-all/',views.RequestExport,name='export_all_requests'),
path('requests/import/',views.RequestImport,name='import_requests'),path('mycompany/<int:pk>/',views.MyCompanyDetail.as_view(),name='my_company_detail'),
```

]

When I click on the following template tag it throws me the error:

href="{% url 'user_console:request_detail' pk=request.pk %}">{{request.pk }}

And I receive the error:

NoReverseMatch at /console/request/201/. Reverse for 'my_company_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['console/(?P[0-9]+)/mycompany/$']

Comment: Your context variable named `request` clashes with a variable added to the context by `django.template.context_processors.request `, one of Django's standard context processors. Use a different name.

Comment: Am I able to still have Request as a Model name and simply use different url pattern naming? Or would i need to refactor all of that code regarding Request?

Comment: You can keep your model name. Just add something like `context_object_name = 'my_request'` to your class based views and use `my_request` instead of `request` in your templates.